# Why deleted answers can not be voted for undelete any more?

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

This site has the feature of voting for undelete but this feature can not be used:

[image]

I remember previously deleted answers could be voted for undelete. but recently this is not possible when an answer is deleted by a mod:

[image]

What is the reason for this change and impossibility of voting for undelete?

Is not it possible that decision of a mod about deleting an answer be wrong?

Why it should not be possible to vote for undelete?

Is not it a kind of dictatorship that users can not vote against decision of a mod?

This is a community site and users should have the role in moderation of site by using their votes.

Also if this feature does not work so why it is there at all?

Comment: Good to see that the community is asking such questions. And clearing their misconceptions (if any).

Comment: Moderators need sometimes to be able to delete content in a way that cannot be overrun but a group of users, that is fine. What creates problems is that moderators cannot cast normal votes even if they want to do so. This goes back to SE software. I personally complained about this a number of times to SE but it doesn't seem to be important for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This feature has been implemented for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86481/132874): Posts deleted by a moderator cannot be undeleted except by a moderator.  If a post is deleted by regular users (either a self-delete or by gathering enough votes-to-delete), it can be voted to undelete like any other.

Just because the community lacks the convenient "vote to undelete" button doesn't mean the community is somehow being oppressed by a dictatorship.  [If the community wants to contest a mod-deletion, they can simply bring it up on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87921/132874).  Posts can easily be flagged for undelete once an appropriate decision is reached.

Comment: but what if a mod only made a mistake somewhere, that doesn't mean the mod should be deleted!!   We want only that post to be undeleted not the mod himself!!