# Why there is this much deletion?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

Today accidentally I noticed that the number of my answers shown in my user page is far less than it was!

And the worse is that I cannot understand what were them and why they were deleted. There's no choice to see the list of my deleted posts.

After spending a lot of time to find my deleted posts, I could just find one of them, which was deleted in spite of having 2 up votes.

I think everyone will admit that deleting one's post without any notification is not fair at all.

Now I want to know that:

1. Based on which policy there has been this much deletion recently?
2. And why there should be this much privilege for an individual moderator to delete users' posts without any notification and no chance for the user to at least vote her post to be undeleted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I have been deleting a large number of posts (the details can be found in my answer on the recent meta post "[Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/983/22)").  Presumably the ones you're asking about were involved in this purge, but I can't explain why any particular post was deleted unless you can point me to an actual deleted answer, as they were deleted for a variety of reasons.  Upvotes, especially in the wake of the current situation, are wholly irrelevant.

Due to the very nature of site-moderation, user posts may end up closed and/or deleted with absolutely no notification.  Because of how difficult it is for me to leave comments in general, and how often said comments are just taken as something to either be argued with or ignored entirely, I have chosen to forego notifications — especially notifications to established users who should already know by now how the site works — unless I feel them to actually be constructive.

For the most part, I chose not to leave comments because it would only be duplicating information already found in [our help centre](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).  Posts which are, among other reasons, very low quality or which don't fundamentally answer the question asked don't belong on the site.

The fact that a regular user cannot cast an undelete vote on a moderator-deleted post is by design, see also the related meta question "[Why deleted answers can not be voted for undelete any more?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/976/22)".

Comment: why it is difficult for you to leave a reason comment? if so why you do not ask help for other mods? or why you do not leave this job if it is difficult?

Comment: @BattleofKarbala Because I have severe difficulty communicating with other people without sounding either rude or patronizing?  Because I often have no idea how to explain things to people when they're so blindingly obvious to me that they shouldn't even *need* a comment?  Because commenting is optional, my job is voluntary, and when I do choose to comment I often get nothing but flak?  At best, any comment I leave would either be something blunt like "This does not answer the question" which really doesn't say anything more than the help centre, or I'd be deliberating over it for an hour.

Comment: many of users come from different Muslim countries which their language is not english and they have a completely different culture than western style countries. they should be trained, not killed. this is not a suitable personality for a moderator. please study here: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/are-users-stupid/ a moderator should have a lot of patience. and I recomment reading this article: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/are-users-stupid/ leaving "This does not answer the question" is also useful and user will not be confused and can focus on one reason and improve his post.

Comment: "_I can't explain why any particular post was deleted unless you can point me to an actual deleted answer_" How can I point you to my deleted answers? They're totally out of my reach. You cannot suppose one to visit 2000+ questions to find her deleted answers.

Comment: @Ezati Actually, I have chosen to take the time to go through your posts and explain *why* I deleted them.

Comment: But these are not all of my deleted posts. As far as I can remember there were some more. The other thing is that I totally disagree with these deletions and find them entirely based on your individual opinion. What can I do now?

Comment: @Ezati One more just happened to be an answer to a deleted *question* which had zero score and had been closed since November of 2012.  If you disagree with any particular deletion, just bring it up in its own meta and let the community decide what to do with it; that's the standard procedure for disputing pretty much anything on SE.

Comment: I would suggest the use of the following comment before deletion, even if the reason is much obvious. This way the author can easily visit their deleted post by just flipping through their inbox. Plus it gives a softer impression then the current *apparent* iron fist. `This post is being deleted because it doesn't meet the site's current policy and standards. To further discuss the matter you could bring it up on [meta] or [chat]. And if a consensus is reached and the decisions are implemented the post shall be undeleted.`