# Why moderators do not mention the exact reason of deletation instead of only leaving a link to help center

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

I see many of posts are deleted by a moderator without clearly mentioning reason for deleted. and instead they leave a link to help center to the user himself go there and find the reason.

sometimes there is a reason in comments. but this is not always. in many cases deleted posts have no reason in comments too.

Also how a user can know the exact reason if he checks the [reasons mentioned in help for deleting answers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) but still see none of them are applicable to his answer?

I see one of moderators who is heavily busy deleting many of answers has said:

> Because of how difficult it is for me to leave comments in general,
>   and how often said comments are just taken as something to either be
>   argued with or ignored entirely, I have chosen to forego notifications
>   — especially notifications to established users who should already
>   know by now how the site works — unless I feel them to actually be
>   constructive

[Why there is this much deletion?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/991/why-there-is-this-much-deletion)

if leaving the reason of delete is hard for such a moderator why he undertake this job? and why he does not ask help for other moderators?

deleting an answer without exact mentioning the reason or supporting the user to improve it is a low quality moderation.

> We generally expect that moderators:
>
> ```
> are patient and fair
> lead by example
> show respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words
> are open to some light but firm moderation to keep the community on track and resolve (hopefully) uncommon disputes and exceptions
> ```

https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: It is very hard to check so many questions as you mentioned above. This job needs much spare time and you must dedicate your self to it. Besides, sometimes (not all the time) the moderator might unconsciously be affected by his own beliefs.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience moderating this site, it is my determination that the community in general rarely if ever treats comments appropriately.  Constructive criticism is often ignored, obvious errors in posts are uncorrected even when pointed out, and notifications of moderator action more often than not turns into a personal argument with the moderator.  I have seen users inappropriately flag posts just because they disagree with a moderator action, personally call out moderators in chat, personally call out moderators in comments to wholly unrelated questions, just because their question got closed or their answer got deleted.

Yet I have rarely if ever seen the user actually correct the problems with the post.

Despite repeated explanations that moderators are merely accelerating what any high-rep user can do, despite repeated explanations that moderators merely enforce community standards rather than set them, users still often treat moderator actions as a personal attack and injustice, demanding it be corrected.  Despite repeated attempts to tell users to take their issues to meta, where the community at large can discuss them, moderators who choose to action a post still get *personally* targetted.

Yet I have rarely if ever seen the user actually attempt discuss the matter with the community.

Moderators often have to deal with flags asking for a post to be deleted, often appropriately so, yet despite the low reputation bar for commenting the flagger often chooses not to leave a comment.  Similarly, users can cast votes to close and even delete without so much as leaving a single comment explaining themselves.  I can only speak for myself here, but even when my close vote was merely one of five needed to close a post I find myself *personally* attacked for not leaving comments.  Similarly, I find myself personally called out to explain site policy, or the Stack Exchange model, despite the fact that that's something that any number of other users can do.

Yet I have rarely if ever seen other users be personally expected to leave notifications.

Frankly, it is my opinion that by leaving comments as I have been only reinforces the long-standing misconception that moderators somehow run this site; by its very nature the diamond by the notification just tends to look somehow more "official".  Moderators are simply users like any other, and Stack Exchange has always been built on the idea of self-moderation, yet even after almost two years of leaving constructive criticism, writing meta posts, patiently explaining how the site works in chat, pointing people to appropriate venues, and just generally keeping the site clean, users *still* haven't quite grasped the fundamental idea that the site is run by the *community*, not the moderators.

For the last few days, I have been not only more strict in deleting posts, but often chose to forego commenting entirely when I did so.

In the wake of that, do you know what happened?  Users actively sought out ways to *improve* their posts, made those corrections, and had them undeleted.  Meta activity effectively *tripled*, and not just from the aggrieved parties.  There have been noticeable increases in not only reviews and constructive flags, but also downvoting on the main site which has been notoriously lacking since the site was founded.  Even post quality in general has improved.

In many cases, by the very same users whose posts were deleted in the first place.

Is this all a result of my lack of comments?  I doubt it, but the fact that months upon months of commenting have failed to achieve anything approaching this can't be overstated.

As a moderator, frequent commenting is suggested as a means to guide users to understand the community norms.  However, the essential aspect there is to *guide users*, and as far as I'm concerned constantly offering the community a carrot they refuse to follow and blindly expecting things to get better is more indicative of "low quality moderation" than a few silent deletions.

I have wielded the carrot for almost two years with little to show for it but gray hair.  I have wielded the stick for a week, and constructive activity has skyrocketed.

So if you ask me why moderators do not always mention the exact reason a post was deleted, my answer will be the same as if you ask me why the moderators do anything: Moderators do what they do because they want the site to succeed.  Just like pretty much every other user on this site, moderators are volunteers who have (among other roles) chosen to take the task of guiding the site to graduation.

And if I thought I could bring this site even one step closer to graduation by abolishing comments altogether, believe me I would suggest it.

Comment: many of posts you have deleted had no critical comment. and if you leave comments of reason of deletion the site will be more succeeded. because the use can improve it. but with no comment author never becomes notified of his deleted post and that post that perhaps is useful is removed from site.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala `if you leave comments of reason of deletion the site will be more succeeded`: Did you even read my post?  I've been leaving comments for almost two years and our site is *still* in beta and I'm *still* deleting low-quality posts for exactly the same reasons (and often from the same *users*); I've so far noticed *little to no significant effect* on anyone's actual behaviour due to my comments.